# Unable to attach eBPF program to eth0 interface on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, xdp-bpf

I am trying to attach an XDP program that prints hello world on receiving a ICMP message onto the eth0 interface on an EC2 ubuntu VM.
I am getting the following error :
`Error: interface xdp attach failed: Invalid argument.`

However I am able to attach the program to the lo loopback interface.
This is the command I am using:
`sudo bpftool net -d attach  xdp name $1 dev $2 overwrite`

Comment: Can you share the full output you get when trying to attach to the eth0 interface with the `-d` flag passed?

Comment: That was the full output. I figured out the issue.  XDP programs can only be attached to interfaces with a maximum mtu of 3840 and the mtu of eth0 was 9000. Once I changed the mtu of eth0 using ifconfig I was able to attach the XDP program.

Comment: @DellwynTennison: how did you find that out? Its a good find

Answer (score 0):

As said by @dellwyn-tennison this is due to the MTU size.
XDP programs can only be attached to interfaces with maximum MTU of 3840.

To find the current MTU of your interfaces:

```
$ ifconfig | grep mtu
```

Change the MTU size of your interface:

```
$ ifconfig <Interface_name> mtu <mtu_size> up
```